# How to use sessionID with express and socket.io

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

I am trying to hold session data across my whole web-app, but I have difficulties to get the same sessionID everywhere.

What's the use of the sessionID inside of this snippet of code (used with express):

```
app.get('/test-page', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.sessionID);
});
```

Every time I open the page I get a new sessionID here.

Furthermore, I am using this code for getting the sessionID from the cookie in my socket.io:

```
io.set('authorization', function(handshakeData, accept) {
    if (handshakeData.headers.cookie) {
        handshakeData.cookie = parseCookie(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
        handshakeData.sessionID = handshakeData.cookie['express.sid'];
    } else {
        handshakeData.sessionID = -1;
    }
    accept(null, true);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('client connected, ssID: ' + socket.handshake.sessionID);
});
```

How to get this same session in app.get('/test-page',... ? Or vice versa.

Comment: you can attach seesion ID with socket object and later use that in 'connection' event also

Answer (score 0):

I never got to figuring this out but you could always do some rewriting to [express.io](http://express-io.org/)

Checkout the [sessions example](https://github.com/techpines/express.io/tree/master/examples#sessions), seems to be exactly what you need.